# How to can implement bootstrap widget code for custom header in WordPress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, header, wordpress-theming

I am working on the website, I am not a pro in bootstrap. Here is  the header I have with the theme:

[image]

I want to replace the address with 3 small png images i.e BBB A+ Accredited Business and Google Partner.

Like this: (Photoshoped)
[image]

Here is the widget code:

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-lg-10 start-xs start-sm">
    <aside id="text-3" class="widget header-right widget_text">
        <div class="textwidget">
            <div class="container extra-info">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5">
                        <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                        <div class="phone">
                            <h3>1-775-97-377</h3>
                            <span>info@thememove.com</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-7 col-md-6">
                        <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
                        <div class="address">
                            <h3>14 Tottenham Court Road</h3>
                            <span>London, England.</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </aside>
</div>
```

Will you please let me know which will be the right tags and code I can use?
I am having an issue with alignment too! `col-md`, I want to hide it in the mobile version (maybe `col-xs`)

Help will be really appreciated!

Comment: Are you wanting to replace just what is inside the address div with three extra boxes that contain the logos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the address contents with another row and the three divs as below. Remember the columns need to add up to 12 for the grid to work as it should.

```
<div class="address">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">logo here</div>
<div class="col-md-4">logo here</div>
<div class="col-md-4">logo here</div>
</div>
```

Also with regard to hiding columns, I know bootstrap has various ways of doing that with the adding of their classes but also look at media queries.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {
.whatever {
display:none;
}
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp